# How to schedule two commands to run at certain times daily on Windows?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I'm on Windows Server 2012 and I need to restart a service at a certain point in time every day. I'm doing this using two commands, `net stop` and `net start`. This is what I have tried so far:

```
SchTasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN "AgentRestart" /TR "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe \c net stop 'test service' && net start 'testservice'" /ST 01:00
```

And

```
At 01:00:00AM /every:M,T,W,TH,F,SA,SU net stop "test service" 

At 01:00:30AM /every:M,T,W,TH,F,SA,SU net start "test service"
```

The first one doesn't work and the second one has a 30 second delay which is not desirable. Any better solutions?

Comment: "The first one doesn't work"  doesn't work in what way exactly?  What happens?  Any error message?   As you have it written here, the `\c` switch's slash in your SchTasks command is wrong; it should be `/c`.

Comment: Nice, glad to hear it worked! :) I stuck it in an official answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\c` switch's slash in your SchTasks command is invalid; it should be `/c`.